# Error on try to add score money or water

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to implement a scoring system in unity3d c# but it seems nothing happens I have added the tag to object were its attach the script and there are no errors but I try to add the score or other nothing change.
I have the collider element on the object and active
but when the player collides it destroy the object but it's not adding the score money and water

this is the triggered code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class waterpicks : MonoBehaviour {

void  OnTriggerEnter (  Collider other   ){
    if (other.tag == "water_bottle1") {
        scoreManager.money += 10;
        scoreManager.score += 10;
        scoreManager.water += 1;

        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

}
}
```

and this is my score system

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class scoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static int score;
public static int money;
public static int level;
public static int water;
public static int drinks;
public Text ShowScore;
public Text Showmoney;
public Text Showlevel;
public Text Showwater;

//public static int frutoscoleta;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    score = 0;
    money = 0;
    level = 0;
    water = 80;
    //PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("scorePref");
    //score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("scorePref");
    //PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("moneyPref");
    //money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("moneyPref");
    //PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("levelPref");
    //level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("levelPref");
    ShowScore.text = "Score : " + score;
    Showmoney.text = "Money : " + money;
    Showlevel.text = "Level : " + level;
    Showwater.text = "Drinks : " + drinks;
 }



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("scorePref", score);
    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("moneyPref", money);
    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("level", level);
    //scoreManager.score++;
    //scoreManager.money++;
    //scoreManager.level++;

}


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens??

Comment: @Ikillnukes i mean wen the player collide with bottle of water it should destroy the object bottle and then add 10 of money 10 of score and 1 of drinks. But wen my player collides with the bottle she's destroy but no adding poinst in to my variables from other script on that case the scoreManager.cs

Comment: How do you know the money isn't added? Debugging??

Comment: well because my text's they are assign with my variables so wen i add one point to score or water it should change my text to if i am not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "show" the text outside the Start, in the update is an option...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class scoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int score;
    public static int money;
    public static int level;
    public static int water;
    public static int drinks;
    public Text ShowScore;
    public Text Showmoney;
    public Text Showlevel;
    public Text Showwater;

    //public static int frutoscoleta;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        money = 0;
        level = 0;
        water = 80;     
     }      

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {            
        ShowScore.text = "Score : " + score;
        Showmoney.text = "Money : " + money;
        Showlevel.text = "Level : " + level;
        Showwater.text = "Drinks : " + drinks;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This should work but it's better for OP to update the texts only when the variables are updated instead of doing it every frame.

Answer (score 4):

The code is running in the `Start` function. The `Start` function runs once only. The `Update` function runs every frame and your increment code should be run outside the Start function.

It's not a good idea to update the `Text` components in the `Update` function since you are performing few string concatenation. Replace all the increment code such as `scoreManager.money += 10` and `scoreManager.score += 10;` with a function then update the `Text` components in each of those functions so that the `Text` components are **only** updated when the the corresponding variable changes.

```
public class Waterpicks : MonoBehaviour
{
    ScoreManager scoreManager;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("ScoreMangerHolder");
        scoreManager = obj.GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "water_bottle1")
        {
            scoreManager.incrementMoney(10);
            scoreManager.incrementScore(10);
            scoreManager.incrementWater(1);

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Score System

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int score;
    public static int money;
    public static int level;
    public static int water;
    public static int drinks;
    public Text ShowScore;
    public Text Showmoney;
    public Text Showlevel;
    public Text Showwater;

    //public static int frutoscoleta;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        money = 0;
        level = 0;
        water = 80;

        ShowScore.text = "Score : " + score;
        Showmoney.text = "Money : " + money;
        Showlevel.text = "Level : " + level;
        Showwater.text = "Drinks : " + drinks;
    }

    public void incrementMoney(int amount)
    {
        money += amount;
        Showmoney.text = "Money : " + money;
    }

    public void incrementScore(int amount)
    {
        score += amount;
        ShowScore.text = "Score : " + score;
    }

    public void incrementWater(int amount)
    {
        water += amount;
        Showwater.text = "Water : " + water;
    }
}
```

This shows you what your code should look like. Notice the capitalization of the class names. I think you should be doing that. You can go ahead and add other functions to update the Texts I did not include. You can also make the `incrementXXX` functions to be `static` and call it directly but that's not necessary.